# Why won't my NSURLSessionDownloadTask download ever reach my client?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, curl, safari, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

My iOS app uses NSURLSessionConfiguration, NSURLSession, NSURLSessionDownloadTask, etc to download an xml file that our server produces on the fly from a database. Everything works fine with the downloads, until I try to download a larger file from one particular account. Our server has to do a lot of work before it can deliver the xml for this account. In other words, there is a somewhat significant wait before the server actually spits out the requested xml. For this largest account, the iOS client never receives the data, even though the server successfully processes the data and reports sending it to the client.

While testing, we noticed something peculiar:

1. We CANNOT download the same XML in any Safari browser (desktop or iOS)
2. We CAN download the XML using Chrome on the desktop
3. We CAN download the XML using curl on the command line
4. In our iOS app, it fails to download the XML on a device or in the simulator

I cranked up both timeoutIntervalForRequest and timeoutIntervalForResource. It isn't "timing out", per se. But it sure seems like something in Apple's networking stack isn't permitting the long wait for the XML to be produced by the server. And why would Chrome and curl have no problems with it, but Safari and my iOS code do? So, I'm somewhat at a loss as to what's happening here.

This is legacy server code and it will be changed in the future to JSON and a faster class, so I don't need any "change your server code" answers.

Any ideas for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have also tried AFNetworking and curl, they all fail in a project. But I can run the same curl in the terminal and it works.

Answer (score 2):

There are two timeouts you'll hit; the first one comes when there's no data for a particular period of time.  The other comes when the request doesn't complete in a particular period of time.  Both of those need to be high enough.  My guess is that the server isn't even sending back a status code within that first timeout, which causes the NSURL stack to assume that the server is dead.

Even if you can tune the parameters to reduce the problem, there's a good chance that the only real answer is "change the server", simply because there's a nonzero chance that (particularly on a cellular connection) the network connection will drop randomly.

The easiest way to solve this would be to write a small wrapper script that, with no parameters:

- Immediately returns a unique identifier (UUID) for the resource.
- Spawns an asynchronous curl job (on the server) to request the resource from the server and write it to a file, with that UUID as the name
- Stores the expected file length provided by libcurl in `My-UUID-Goes-Here.meta` or similar.
- Deletes the file if anything goes wrong.

or with a UUID parameter:

- Makes sure the UUID is a proper UUID without any special characters.
- Checks to see if there's a file with that UUID in a particular directory, and verifies that the file is complete.
- If the file is incomplete, provides the number of bytes received and the total expected number of bytes (or just says "not ready").
- Otherwise, returns the file and immediately deletes it.

It's probably ten lines of code—twenty tops—plus maybe a two-line cron script to clean up any files that are more than a day old.

Then at that point, your app can just ask for the data and get back the UUID.  It can then periodically ask the server if it has the data yet, and it will get back an instant response that says either "Here's the data" or "Nope.  Not yet".

Comment: Interesting response, thanks! 

Yes, I have both timeout values set sky high.